# Compare 2 cells for maximum value, but if one of the cell has a text then return that particular text else return max value

Tags: microsoft-excel

Am pretty new to excel, I need help with the below situation
I compare 2 cells let's say B2 and C2 and return the Maximum value in A2, but when comparing both the cells if there is any specific text instead of a number then return that text else return the maximum Value.

Example B2=2 and C2=1 return 2 "but if B2=2 & C2=Under review then returns "Under review".

Can anyone help me a formula to solve this please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following formula to a new colummn e.g. first cell `D1`.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(C1),MAX(B1,C1),C1)
```

- Select the cell that has the formula
- Rest your cursor in the lower-right corner so that it turns into a plus sign (+)
- Drag the fill handle down, up, or across the cells that you want to fill.

This is resulting in:

[image]

BTW - you can also press Ctrl+D to fill the formula down in a column. First select the cell that has the formula you want to fill, then select the cells underneath it, and then press Ctrl+D.

**Edit** (originally not asked but added according to the comment)

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(B1),ISNUMBER(C1)),MAX(B1,C1),IF(ISNUMBER(B1),C1,B1))
```

[image]

Comment: If B4 is a text value, the formula is returning C4 instead of B4.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, however, If B5 is Under review instead of C5 then still i want the return value as Under review in D5. Any suggestion pls

Comment: @Reddy Lutonadio - agreed.

Comment: @Anly Henry - You're welcome. See my edit (parallel processing ;-) - two answers).

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Thank you again, But I have one more concern that popped up right now as I was working, what if there are many cells with Numbers let's say A1, B1, C1, D1, and even if one of the cells has "Under review", then I need the return value as Under review in cell E1, else return the maximum value among all the cells in E1. Can you help me in this

Comment: Good day @ReddyLutonadio!! I hope you replied to my query Yesterday.But for some odd reason, I do not see the reply now.I refreshed the page multiple times but in vain. Do you mind sending the response again to me, please? Thank you

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio. Sorry to bother you, but if you could respond to me, I will just try to work it out and solve the issue. I will appreciate your response. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of `IF`, `AND`, `ISNUMBER` and `MAX` functions.

`AND(ISNUMBER(B2),ISNUMBER(C2))` checks whether both cells are numbers. If true, the maximum of the two cells is returned. If false, B2's value is checked. If it's a number C2 is returned. If not, B2 is returned.

Note that if both cells are text, B2 will be returned.

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(B2),ISNUMBER(C2)),MAX(B2:C2),IF(ISNUMBER(B2),C2,B2))
```

[image]

Comment: Its workingggggggg!!!!!!!! Thank you So much.

Comment: @AnlyHenry See [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: @AnlyHenry If the text is always the same (in this case "under review"), then you can use the formula `=IF(PRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(A2:C2));MAX(A2:C2);"Under Review")` as seen on this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnRAz.png). If there are different texts, then you might need multiple IFs.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will try this solution.

Comment: Thank you . However, let’s say am applying the formula in cell D4. I want to compare the cells G4, I4, L4, N4, Q4, S4, V4, & X4 (not a continuous range but intermediate) & I want the return value as Max value if all the above-mentioned cells have a number, but if any of the above-mentioned cells has a text “UR” then return that text. Can you please help me??